# Decoding activation context error 0xC015000f

Tags: debugging, windbg, usermode, activation-context-api

I need to identify the root cause of

> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc015000f - The activation context being deactivated is not the most recently activated one.

using a user mode post mortem crash dump.

Callstack:

```
#  ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
00 0d31f948 7535544c 096c59b0 *1fb2adc6* 0d31f9a4 ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContext+0x154
01 0d31f958 74739882 00000000 *1fb2adc6* 221075b3 kernel32!DeactivateActCtx+0x31
02 0d31f964 221075b3 856c9c2c 0e4827d4 0e482768 mfc100u!AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2::~AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2+0x1d
04 0d31f9a4 221093ce 856c9c74 00000000 00000000 dd10shrd!ClsVDctNotifySink::XDgnVDctNotifySink::JITPause_+0x93
```

I'm pretty sure that `0x1fb2adc6` is the `ulCookie` value that's passed into the `DeleteActCtx` call (i.e. `DeactivateActCtx( 0, 0x1fb2adc6 )`), but I don't know where to go next to determine why it's being deactivated out of context.

I can't re-run the program with special exception settings; this user mode crash dump we received from a customer installation is all I've got to work with.

Output from `!PEB` shows the following about the environment:

```
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2502
```

Comment: Should also say that we are not using any explicit calls to the activation context API, so whatever's doing this, it's happening somewhat automatically.

Comment: This is the same call stack that is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2009/12/15/troubleshooting-mfc-state-related-issues.aspx. Try following the steps described int the blog and you might be able to obtain name of DLL that corrupted MFC state.